# How to optimize the process when loading data for the component "select"?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use the `select` component and I want to somehow optimize the process if 200+ data is loaded into the component.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <mat-label>Work</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="works_id">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let work of works" [value]="work.work_id">
      {{work.work_name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

What can be done o that with a large amount of data there are no braking?

Comment: You could replace it with autocomplete input and implement dynamic search with XHR request in background

Comment: @user11277006 your problem not clear. if i'm understanding your problem you have to check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5tnz3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Abhishek You simply displayed a large amount of data in the component and everything, as a result, everything slows down. I will try to make an option `PatrykUszyński`